# nginx route all 404 requests to a php script

Tags: nginx, php-fpm, fastcgi

I want to route all 404 requests to a php script, How should I do that? My nginx config is:

```
server {
    listen 81;
    listen [::]:81;
    root /srv/http/paste.lan/www;
    autoindex on;
    client_max_body_size 20M;
    index index.txt index.html index.htm index.php;
    server_name paste.lan;
    location / {
        # First attempt to serve request as file, then
        # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    # pass PHP scripts to FastCGI server
    #
    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    #
    #   # With php-fpm (or other unix sockets):
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php8.2-fpm.sock;
    #   # With php-cgi (or other tcp sockets):
    #   fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    }


    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    #
    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

Things I have tried:

Attempt #1:

```
    location / {
        # First attempt to serve request as file, then
        # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
    }
```

- This only works for URI's that does not end with .php , for example `/DoesNotExist.ph` is passed to index.php , but `/DoesNotExist.php` get the standard nginx 404 page.

Attempt #2:

```
    location / {
        # First attempt to serve request as file, then
        # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
    error_page 404 /index.php;
```

This sort-of works, all 404 requests are passed to index.php ***but*** this forces the response code to be 404, even if index.php contains:

```
<?php
http_response_code(200);
die("index.php");
```

it will still be served with response code 404 :(

Attempt #3:

```
    location / {
        # First attempt to serve request as file, then
        # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
    error_page 404 =200 /index.php;
```

This also sort-of works, all 404 requests are passed to index.php ***but*** this forces the response code to be 200, even if index.php contains:

```
<?php
http_response_code(400);// HTTP 400 Bad Request
die("index.php");
```

it will still be served as HTTP 200 OK :(

Comment: Almost there, the one you want is `error_page 404 = /index.php;` [to respond with the code it returns](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#error_page). Also, you may want to add `try_files $uri =404;` to your `location ~ \.php$` block to catch non-existent PHP files.

Comment: @RichardSmith dang that works! and i don't need to add anything to the \.php$ block! want to post it as an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `error_page` directive includes an option to change the response code to another.

From [the manual page](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#error_page):

> If an error response is processed by a proxied server or a
> FastCGI/uwsgi/SCGI/gRPC server, and the server may return different
> response codes (e.g., 200, 302, 401 or 404), it is possible to respond
> with the code it returns:
>
> error_page 404 = /404.php;

You should use:

```
error_page 404 = /index.php;
```